# a healthy perspective on "knowing everything"

Tags: soft-question, education

This is a question about attitude, but related to math studies. I have trouble with two things: 1. making "normal" progress in my learning and 2. having the satisfaction that I understand what is going on.

My experience in university (where "normal" progress occurs) suggests that at least 50% of the math learning is just "remembering". My *feeling* is that nobody spent any significant amount of time trying to prove the main theorems in the book on their own. The main theorems were read, remembered, and then used in exercises. But doesn't this kind of education violate the ethos of the activity? If I don't know why a main theorem works, is it kosher to keep reading and developing more theory on top? This seems to be "what people do" and how learning is done.

When I approach my math education, I want to hold myself to the standard where I fully understand the ins and outs of the main ideas before I proceed. But this slows progress significantly. I get the feeling that I should just accept that there are things that I won't have time to understand that I should nevertheless believe. But "believing" without "understanding" makes me uncomfortable...

I would appreciate input on this.

Comment: I think its acceptable to first try to learn how a theorem is used, and then later go back and try to understand why it is true. Otherwise, applied math would be impossibly hard, because you'd already need to know a lot of pure math to even get started (e.g. a proof of Picard-Lindelof), which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: Math aren't reducible to learning theorems and understanding their ins and the outs. I remember having had this kind of "spleen" at a certain step of my studies. I understood later on, by using them, first in computer science, then in image processing that mathematics (applied or pure) is first of all an activity. Solving problems, for you, for the others, that's great fun. What is your level of study ?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are a bunch of questions you can ask about a theorem. What does it say? What can I do with it? How can it be extended? What is the gist of the proof? Does the proof introduce any novel concepts which can be used elsewhere? Does essentially the same proof apply in another context? I would say that, at the level of really learning mathematics (as opposed to being able to pass mathematics courses), all of these questions are more important than "what is the proof?"

Comment: I have often found that it has taken *years* for me to gain enough perspective to be able to understand why a particular theorem is considered important, or to have an idea of how proofs tend to go in a particular subfield. I wouldn't worry too much about this.

Answer (score 1):

We are always "chunking" knowledge—grouping small results into a unified, memorable result while often forgetting the pieces themselves.  I learned how to invert a matrix *by hand* many years ago, but for the last several decades have used software to invert matrices, never performed it by hand.

Think of driving a car.  Do you really need to know how a catalytic converter works to drive a car?  Of course not.  But if you're designing and engine, well then certainly.

So the level at which you "chunk" or group your knowledge depends upon the tasks at hand.  If you're an *applied* mathematician, you will more likely profit from having great *breadth* of knowledge, i.e., knowing what theorems and techniques might be useful in your problem.  If you're a *theoretical* or *pure* mathematician, then you will more likely profit from having great *depth* of knowledge.  (Of course the greatest mathematicians have both.)

Moreover, you may find that *just using* your mathematical knowledge will lead to greater understanding.  I studied multi-variate calculus in high school and did fine, but (like you) there were several results that I "merely memorized" and couldn't fully explain.  However, when I *used* this mathematics in physics class, *then* I understood the math.

So... don't worry that you don't understand every element of all the math you learn.  Some of that math you'll never use, but the math that you *do* use, you'll gain deeper understanding from using it.

Comment: it's true that I don't need to know why something works to use it. but if I have no means to verify that it works in an objective sense (like you can verify that your car runs), then I ought to be confident in the logic that implies it. no? i don't see the value of learning something that 1. can't be empirically verified or 2. i don't understand logically.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level of math you're in. In a course, you should know why a math theorem works, which can mean anything from reproducing its full proof to remembering the main idea of it to remembering whatever clever tricks it involves, depending on its importance and complexity. If you're doing math research and publishing results, you should have a better understanding of what results you're invoking (which doesn't necessarily require building them up from scratch yourself). The point of math is to understand the subject and prove more results, not merely to snap other people's results together like Legos and treat the subject as a black box to solve equations or analyze experiments with. In a course, you're definitely responsible for understanding the proofs of results, rather than just being able to regurgitate and apply them.

That having been said, I freely use the Feit-Thompson theorem, for example, despite unable to tell you much about it besides the final result. Some theorems are quite involved but manageable in a class: the $h$-cobordism theorem and Mostow rigidity, for example, are usually covered in classes on their respective subjects, although they take many sessions to prove. But that's fine; the point of those classes is to understand more about the subject than just the packages results themselves, and knowing the proof allows you to prove related things. The Whitney trick, for example, involved in the proof of the $h$-cobordism theorem pops up everywhere in high-dimensional topology.